# How can I define relationships for my models in flask

Tags: flask, orm, model, flask-sqlalchemy, relationship

I am new to flask and ORM technology and am doing one sample project for my learning.

In my application, a trainer can teach one or more technologies, so I define my tables as below:

1. Trainer:

   - id
   - name
   - phone
   - email
2. Technology:

   - id
   - tech_name
3. Assert:

   - id
   - trainer_id
   - technology_id

Can anyone help me on how to convert the above table definitions into models with proper relationships?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a Many to Many relationship. The Flask-SQLAlchemy documentation supplies an [example of that here.](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/models.html#many-to-many-relationships)

You have the right idea about having a table to link them together, but you don't really require the `id` column in there, below is the example bent to your models.

```
technologies = db.Table('technologies',
    db.Column('trainer_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('trainer.id')),
    db.Column('tech_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tech.id'))
)

class Trainer(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    phone = db.Column(db.String)
    email = db.Column(db.String)
    technologies = db.relationship('Tech', secondary=technologies,
        backref=db.backref('trainers', lazy='dynamic'))

class Tech(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
```

So now you can add Trainers, and Techs, then assign them as required:

```
nano_tech = Tech(name='Nano')
mega_tech = Tech(name='Mega')
bob = Trainer(name='Bob', email='Whatever', technologies=[nano_tech, mega_tech])
```

Or you could add existing technologies to an existing trainer

```
trainer = Trainer.query.filter_by(name='Alice').first()
tech = Tech.query.filter_by(name='Super').first()
trainer.technologies.append(tech)
```

Or any combination therein.

Comment: thanks for your answer :) and i need to add technologies at time of creation of Trainer record ??

Comment: You don't have to, I'll add an example

Comment: how can i retrieve trainer info based on technology

Comment: Lots of ways, say you have a tech object already `nano = Tech.query.filter_by(name='Nano').first()` you can find all the trainers by just doing `trainers = nano.trainers`.  Or you could filter at the same time like `trainers = Trainer.query.filter(Trainer.technologies.any(name='Nano').all()` or by joining to the Tech table `trainers = Trainer.query.join(Trainer.technologies).filter(Tech.name == 'Nano').all()`